# 403 Error when trying to remove products from Cart

Tags: php, server, e-commerce, opencart, cpanel

I am using a cPanel host and running PHP 5.5. Opencart version 1.5.1.

When I try to remove a product from the cart I am getting a 403 forbidden error.

This only seems to happen with products that have a lot of options and include text input options.

I have tried a clean install and the same thing is happening.

I am assuming it has something to do with the server configuration.

I found some information indicating that `suhosin.get.max_value_length` might be the problem, but my server is using PHP 5.5 (no suhosin). I have tried increasing `max_input_vars`, but it doesn't seem to help

Example of remove from cart URLS used to remove products from cart:

**The following URL works:**

> cart&remove=50:YTo0OntpOjI7czoyOiIxNiI7aToxO3M6MToiOCI7aTozO3M6NToiUlVDVFkiO2k6NDtzOjEwOiIwNDY2NjE1ODA4Ijt9:

**The following URL does not work:**

> cart&remove=61:YTo0OntpOjQyO3M6MzoiMjQwIjtpOjQxO3M6MzoiMjM2IjtpOjQzO3M6NToiUlVTVFkiO2k6NDQ7czoxMDoiMDQ2NjYxNTgwOCI7fQ==:

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked your error log?

Comment: I have checked the error log in both Opencart and cPanel and I am not receiving any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see you are getting 403 forbidden error that means mod_Security is blocking your access with that URL. I will suggest you please contact your server admin and ask them to check Apache error logs of your domain. They can find exact root cause of your issues.

Comment: Thank you so much, I contacted the host and it was indeed a mod_Security issue. I really appreciate your help, been stressing about this all week!